# Trying to access most recently downloaded file - Java

Tags: java, csv, file

I have a java bot that downloads a csv file and then I am parsing the CSV file by getting the path name for the most recently downloaded file. For some reason, when I call my function to get the most recent download, it gets the second most recent download, but if I call the function again, it successfully obtains the most recently downloaded file. Attached I have pictures of the function that downloads the CSV file and a picture of where I called the function in main. Please help.

[Top part of code is the main function where I call the getRecentDownloadCSV in main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohez5.png)

The output:

> End reading my file
> Recent Download file name = C:\Users\MyUsername\Downloads\export_2020-12-03 16_55_21.csv
> Recent Download file name = C:\Users\MyUsername\Downloads\export_2020-12-03 17_00_53.csv
> SYSO getRecentDownloadCSV = C:\Users\MyUsername\Downloads\export_2020-12-03 17_00_53.csv

As you can see in the output, the first recent download file name is incorrect. The bottom two are correct. Can anyone tell me how I can prevent calling this function twice and successfully obtain the most recent download on the first function call? Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please edit your question to actually contain the code as text.

Comment: Your code reads the list of files, waits for 5 seconds and then processes this (5 seconds old) list. That doesn't make sense. Read the list of files just before you want to process it.

Comment: If I do not use the sleep thread, the process will fail to obtain the most recent download. With the sleep thread, it successfully obtains the most recent download.

Comment: @sql_user11: but apparently it **doesn't** successfully obtain the most recent download. I gather that your problem is actually a race condition: something actually writes the files in the 5 seconds. That's why the first call (which looks for the files and *then* sleeps) fails and the second one succeeds. Also: **post your code**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use getRecentDownloadCSV() twice in header. Try to remove first on the second call.

Try to use this in your code

```
for(int i = 1; files.length-1; i++){
if(theNewestFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()){
theNewestFile = files[i];
}
```